# How to parse dynamically generated HTML page in android

Tags: android

After consuming a REST API I get the response as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="spr.aspx" id="form1">
         <div class="aspNetHidden">           <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />          </div>
         <div class="aspNetHidden">           <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value=" /wEdAAKvVXD1oYELeveMr0vHCmYPexh68czOUCZr7Ag7DJmz7Z+a1vpqAoNCsL3bMp63kqR0V0mUiq3TIIVw+e5c39X2" />          </div>
         <div></div>
         <input name="ResponseCipher" type="hidden" id="ResponseCipher" value="irvN4mdV6jA0wmsSVq8yHv3F+2frLchvQpTuJj1r8lBMmYhP8ZJ5TmVGbdm1vPm91UEW3m89IgfgM5R+HjF8jwzskTX4sRExSbDv3szDdwRyUnAT9neieDJDXzd CmG6/+FhxIN/Lai0Dg5s7lWfGsl+xNmsTr/4yQ//btMl1u6AM+Jyi2+tBwGPgjMgrG5hjnqpbKwsd5k7yELDdCQHLzkjFagKjYMyfXgaRlHX7rNBpiQSKqmhESZm/Xrkty SfOrf80jFQtUZq0iSHxVr83W55/QGhH0TFs+avcP4yVJPuwCju2bH0Kkd6m3QtclygPM29mc2xIyIxl/8SB3bgJ8ESwWJCImIvqXJa1rcSO8y5UYkn+QL5cI9iuAaEhGjl woC3q/q6F9kQrSlnV4ExymTio0VLFUSN4Sx6GjV5E2ITT25ypspkp05FvQPZnp+8S" />         
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">  document.forms[0].action='https://il01addproc.propay.com/Return.aspx';  document.forms[0].submit(); </script>
```

This page is generated dynamically. I went through tutorial of `jsoup`. Here, it is generated dynamically and this page is given as response. So is there any way to process this dynamic page?

Comment: process? what do you mean by that? to show it on `WebView`?

Comment: No, I want to have it in `Log.i("parameter" + ResponseCipher)` statement

Comment: so whats the problem with `jsoup`?

Comment: "REST API"? Are you sure? And by the way this response is not valid xhtml, in spite of it's claim.

Comment: @Henry, yes I am sure. It is third party API

Comment: @pskink in `Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();` I have to enter the url from which I am parsing, but here it is the reponse generated dynamically.

Comment: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string

Comment: @pskink I got your point. Thanks for the answer